# When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing my component

**ForecastButtons.js**

```
export const ForecastButtons = ({ city }) => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(null)

  const getData = () => {
    fetchCityData(city).then((payload) => setPayload(payload));
  }
  const location = payload?.location?.name;
  const currentTemp = payload?.current?.temp_c;

  return(
    <div className="sm:col-span-2">
      <p className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Select forecast</p>
        <button onClick={getData} className="mt-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded" type='button'>
          Today
        </button>
        <p key={city?.location?.id} className='my-5'>
          { location ? `Current weather in ${location} is ${currentTemp} degrees ` : 'Please search for city to see current weather'}
        </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the part of my test:

```
    test('render weather into component',  async () => {
    
      const { getByText } = render(<ForecastButtons weather={weatherResponce} city={'London'} />);
      const button = getByText('Today')
    
      await act(async () => {
        await fireEvent.click(button)
      })
      expect(getByText('London')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
```

Please be aware, it's not the whole test, just the part, which is not working. The error is above. As you can see, I added the `act()` to it, but it still keeps throwing the error: When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...)

Comment: Clicking the button just _starts_ the process, the component gets updated when the request (or whatever test double you're hopefully using for that, without a [mre] it's unclear) _finishes_. Look into RTL's async matchers.

Comment: _"dispatchEvent passes the test though"_ - what test? That doesn't appear in what you've shown. And I'm not stalking you, if I've responded to multiple questions (which I can't see from any of your recent posts) I guess you've been asking in tags like [tag:jestjs] in which I'm active. This is a public site, you don't get to choose who sees your questions, and other people can still come and engage.

Comment: I'm simply not going to do that. SO is about the _content_, not the _user_; I'm not going to maintain some list of people who've asked me to ignore their questions. I don't see what's negative about what I've posted, even - the MRE requirement is a basic one in [ask] and I've suggested something that you can look into to solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't answered this question, nobody has downvoted it and you can't vote to delete something that's still open. There is a lot of content in the [help] explaining the site processes. I've _commented_, suggesting both a topic to research to solve your own problem and a way to improve the question which would increase the likelihood of getting a solution here. I really can't see why you're responding in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could find some hint in [React Testing Library and the “not wrapped in act” Errors](https://davidwcai.medium.com/react-testing-library-and-the-not-wrapped-in-act-errors-491a5629193b) on Medium, where are a lot of cases are explained very well.

First useful learning:

> React testing library already integrated `act` with its APIs. So in most
> cases, we do not need to wrap `render` and `fireEvent` in `act`. For
> example:
>
> ```
> // With react-testing-library
> it("should render and update a counter", () => {
>   // Render a component
>   const { getByText } = render(<Counter />;
>   ...  
>
>   // Fire event to trigger component update
>   fireEvent.click(getByText("Save"));
>   ...
> });
> ```

In my case I got the error (my assumption as a beginner), because `fireEvent.click` triggers `fetchData` to be called, which is an asynchronous call. When its response comes back, `fetchCityData`/`getData` will be invoked, but at this moment, the update will happen outside of React’s call stack.

**Solution**

Before assertions, wait for component update to fully complete by using waitFor. `waitFor` is an API provided by React Testing Library to wait for the wrapped assertions to pass within a certain timeout window.

I changed my bit of test code as follows:

```
  test('renders responce into paragraph', async () => {
    render(<ForecastButtons weatherResponce={weatherResponce} city='London' />);
    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    const label = screen.getByText('Please search for city to see current weather');
    fireEvent.click(button)
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(label.textContent).toBe(`Current weather in ${weatherResponce.location.name} is ${weatherResponce.current.temp_c} degrees`);
    });
  })
```

`weatherResponce` is just a mocked response to a mocked HTTP request, which I am doing with nock.

Comment: Despite your objections [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391350/when-testing-code-that-causes-react-state-updates-should-be-wrapped-into-act/69394427#comment122649360_69391350) _did_ cover this - it's because the component renders when the "request" completes, and RTL's async API is a solution. Also note that `nock` specifically isn't relevant, you'd see the issue with other test doubles, but if you don't provide a complete example (`nock` isn't mentioned, `fetchCityData` isn't defined) we can't run it locally to recreate and thereby help solve the problem.